# How to use git command line to get the date when a repository was first built?

Tags: git

Getting the date when the first commit was been given is also okay.

I have been trying `git log` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Define "doesn't work"

Answer (score 2):

Probably a better method, but this was the first thing that popped into my head:

```
$ git show $(git log --oneline | tail -n 1 | cut '-d ' -f 1) | grep '^Date:'
Date:   Sun Mar 28 19:56:29 2010 -0600
```

The subshell will get a hash of the first commit, then I `grep` for a line starting with `Date:`.  Probably many cases where it doesn't work, but it should at least get you started.